# ruby openssl.so: 14001 error

Tags: ruby, openssl, side-by-side

When trying to run a simple ruby program I wrote, I am getting this error.  Just reinstalled everything the other day, before the code was working fine.

ruby/1.8/i386-mswin32/openssl.so: 14001: The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log for more detail.  - C:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-mswin32/openssl.so (LoadError)

application event log:
Activation context generation failed for "C:\ruby\bin\SSLEAY32.dll". Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC90.CRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8" could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.

Comment: I really wish you luck with this POS, I had similar problems with latest version of OpenCV and just gave up. :)

Comment: SO what does the application log (aka windows event viewer) say about what exactly is the problem

Comment: lol, I was wondering where the application log was.  It says:
Activation context generation failed for "C:\ruby\bin\SSLEAY32.dll". Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC90.CRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8" could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.
Any idea what this means?

Answer (score 1):

Needed the visual c++ redistributable package.  Thanks for the help jitter, you comment lead me to the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem also for me. Installing   [Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9B2DA534-3E03-4391-8A4D-074B9F2BC1BF&displaylang=en) resolved the problem